# Reset looping setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am able to add a row to my table every few seconds using `setTimeout()`. But when I try to reset the table and fill it up again, some of the rows from last time still show up. I would like to reset the whole table and start over from 0.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#btn-start').click(() => {
      showMoves();
  });
  $('#btn-reset').click(() => {
      $('#table-moves tbody tr').remove();
      clearTimeout(timer);
  });
});

var timer;

function showMoves () {
  const moves = ['nf3','d5','g3', 'g6'] // ...
  $('#table-moves tbody tr').remove();
  for (let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        $('#tbody-moves').append(`<tr><td>${i + 1}</td><td>${moves[i]}</td></tr>`);        
    }, 2000 * i);
    if (i >= moves.length - 1) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHO7h.png)

Comment: You're creating multiple timers but assigning them all to the same variable. You probably need to store an array of timeout IDs. I'm not sure what this line is supposed to do: `if (i >= moves.length - 1) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }` A snippet that doesn't run isn't very useful, may as well just show the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setTimeout is an asynchronous function so while you iterate over `moves` you create N timers. So to reset them all you need to store them

````js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#btn-start').click(() => {
      showMoves();
  });
  $('#btn-reset').click(() => {
      $('#table-moves tbody tr').remove();
      while(timers.length) clearTimeout(timers.shift()) // Added
  });
});

var timers = []; // Change

function showMoves () {
  const moves = ['nf3','d5','g3', 'g6'] // ...
  $('#table-moves tbody tr').remove();
  for (let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
    /*Change*/timers.push(setTimeout(() => {
        $('#tbody-moves').append(`<tr><td>${i + 1}</td><td>${moves[i]}</td></tr>`);        
    }, 2000 * i));
    if (i >= moves.length - 1) {
      clearTimeout(timers.pop()); // Change
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: This indeed fixed the problem. Thank you for helping out!